# Why graphic points dont join together when there is another existing graphic line?

Tags: laravel, chart.js

Hello i am working with ChartJs to make a graphic that gets its values from API using laravel. I have a problem that if i have more then 1 graphic line the other graphic dots will not connect with each other to form the line.

This is my `blade` code:

```
    <div class="graph">
            <form>
                @csrf
            <label for="startdate">Start Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate"/>
            <label for="enddate">End Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Shfaq vlerat">
            </form>
        <div class="card text-center m-5">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2>Currency Outlay</h2>
            </div>
            <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas>
        </div>

<script>

    var albanianLek = [], americanDollar = [], euro = [], britishPound = [], created_date = []

    async function dummyChart() {
        await getData()

        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

        const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'line',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: {
                labels: created_date,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'ALL',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
                    data: albanianLek
                },
                    {
                        label: 'GBP',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 153, 153)',
                        data: britishPound
                    },

                    {
                        label: 'USD',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 153, 0)',
                        data: americanDollar
                    },

                    {
                        label: 'EUR',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
                        data: euro
                    },

                ]
            },

            // Configuration options go here
            options: {
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index'
                }
            }
        })}

    dummyChart()


    //Fetch Data from API

    async function getData() {
        const apiUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/outlay";

        const response = await fetch(apiUrl)

        const barChatData = await response.json()

        const ALL = barChatData[0].map((item) => {
            return item.value_with_currencies.ALL;
        })

        const USD = barChatData[0].map((item) => {
            return item.value_with_currencies.USD;
        })

        const EUR = barChatData[0].map((item) => {
            return item.value_with_currencies.EUR;
        })

        const GBP = barChatData[0].map((item) => {
            return item.value_with_currencies.GBP;
        })

        const date = barChatData[0].map((item) => {
            return item.updated_at;
        })

        albanianLek = ALL
        britishPound = GBP
        americanDollar = USD
        euro = EUR
        created_date = date
    }
</script>
```

This is my `api.php` code:

```
Route::get('outlay/{startdate?}/{enddate?}',[GetValuesController::class,'getOutlays']);
```

And this is my `Controller` code:

```
 function getOutlays(Request $request)
    {
        $startdate = $request->startdate;
        $enddate = $request->enddate;

        if($startdate == null && $enddate == null)
        {
            $values = response()->json([OutlayResource::collection(Outlay::where("status", Status::CONFIRMED_BY_EMPLOYEE)->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get())], 200);
        }
        else
        {
            $values = response()->json([OutlayResource::collection(Outlay::where("status", Status::CONFIRMED_BY_EMPLOYEE)->whereBetween("updated_at", [$startdate, $enddate])->orderBy('updated_at', 'asc')->get())], 200);
        }

        return $values;
    }
```

This is what the graphic looks like now:

[image]

As you can see the red graph is working good but the 2 green dots are shown but **not** connected, if the red graph would be removed the green dots would connect. I have another `api` that includes name age and salary and the its the same graphic in `blade` and it works fine, this is how it shows up:

[image]

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably *(since I don't know how your data looks like)*, that you have missing values in the chart dataset of the green line chart.  You could fix this with simply setting the `x` and `y` position of the dataset.

You could achieve this simply with the `map` and `filter` function. Details how this can be done, you can see in the demo below.

**Demo showcase:**
*(the solution is the ** dark green** line, that is offset by -10)*

```js
let dataForGreenLine = [10,  undefined, undefined, 40,  undefined, 30]

let dataset = {
  label: '"Red" - line',
  data:[65, 59, 48, 2, 56, 10 ],
  borderColor: '#ff0000',
  backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
};

let dataset2 = {
  label: '"Green" - line',
  data: dataForGreenLine,
  borderColor: '#00ff00',
  backgroundColor: '#00ff00',
}

let dataset3 = {
  label: 'Solution: "Green" - line (offset -10)',
  
  // cleaning up the data, removing the empty values
  data: dataForGreenLine
            // create the points ( for the demo I'm offsetting "y" by -10)
            // .map((v, i) => ({ x: i, y: v })) 
            .map((v, i) => ({ x: i, y: v? v - 10 : v })) 
            // filtering Points out, that are not valid
            .filter( i => i.y != undefined),
  borderColor: '#009605',
  backgroundColor: '#009605',
}

let config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: dataset.data.map((v,i) => i),
      datasets: [dataset, dataset2, dataset3 ]
    },
    options:{
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      plugins: {
        legend: { display: true }
      }
    }
 };
  
 new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>    

<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```